# Need a single border for stacked bar graph in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I am getting a border for each data in a stacked bar graph.

ChartOptions :

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked bar chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumption'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        reversed: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [{
            y: 5,
          borderColor: 'red',
          borderWidth: 4
        }, 3, 4, 7, 2]
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [{y: 2,
          borderColor: 'red',
          borderWidth: 4}, 2, 3, 2, 1]
    }, {[enter image description here][1]
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [{y: 3,
          borderColor: 'red',
          borderWidth: 4}, 4, 4, 2, 5]
    }]
});
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/chay2443/pen/vYKNmeq)

I want something like this
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55yFM.png)

Kindly help me with the correct ChartOptions which gives a single border around the bar without multiple borders around each bar.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: what are you looking for exactly?

Comment: Hi @Krishna Chaitanya, Do you want to have borders only on a single bar? Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3jntr5a4/

Comment: @MarcelloPerri  please check out the updated question.

Comment: @ppotaczek checkout the updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add fake series with a border and update it dynamically depending on changes on the chart or render a custom shape to simulate borders.

```
    series: [..., {
        showInLegend: false,
        stacking: false,
        data: [10],
        grouping: false,
        color: 'transparent',
        borderWidth: 4,
        borderColor: 'red'
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gtLm9hqk/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#rect

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, Thank you so much for your reply. With the first approach how can I solve these two issues 1. How to add a border for 2 nd column i.e, for Oranges 2. The hover effect is missing for the stacked bar graph

Comment: Hi @Krishna Chaitanya, 1. Change `zIndex` property for the fake series. 2. Just add another data point. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/v0zhrdk6/

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to remove the red border, here is the solution:

```css
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked bar chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumption'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        reversed: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [{
            y: 5,
          borderWidth: 1
        }, 3, 4, 7, 2]
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [{
          y: 2,
          borderWidth: 1}, 2, 3, 2, 1]
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [{
          y: 3,
          borderWidth: 1}, 4, 4, 2, 5]
    }]
});
```

Comment: thanks for replying, Kindly check out the updated question.